# BigQuery on .NET Core - Error on insertion

Tags: c#, .net, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I'm developing a Google Cloud Function with .NET Core 3.1, and I'm also using BigQuery Library on C#.

When I try to make a insertion like so:

```
BigQueryResults newResult = client.ExecuteQuery(
        @$"INSERT {table} 
        (deal_id,
         deal_name,
         deal_amount,
         deal_deal_stage_name,
         deal_cf_tipos_de_operao,
         deal_cf_vidas,
         deal_cf_faturamento_estimativa,
         deal_cf_vigncia_mmaaaa,
         deal_cf_agenciamento,
         deal_cf_comisso_mensal,
         deal_cf_valor_por_vida,
         deal_cf_produto,
         deal_cf_benefcios,
         deal_closed_date,
         created_at,
         updated_at)

        VALUES(
            {newRequest.deal_id},
            '{newRequest.deal_name}',
            {Convert.ToInt32(newRequest.deal_amount)},
            '{newRequest.deal_deal_stage_name}',
            '{newRequest.deal_cf_tipos_de_operao}',
            {newRequest.deal_cf_vidas},
            {newRequest.deal_cf_faturamento_estimativa},
            '{newRequest.deal_cf_vigncia_mmaaaa}',
            {newRequest.deal_cf_agenciamento},
            {newRequest.deal_cf_comisso_mensal},
            {newRequest.deal_cf_valor_por_vida},
            '{newRequest.deal_cf_produto}',
            '{newRequest.deal_cf_benefcios}',
            '{newRequest.deal_closed_date}',
            '{newRequest.created_at}',
            '{newRequest.updated_at}')",
        null)
        .ThrowOnAnyError();
```

But I get the following error:

```
The service bigquery has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
    Could not cast literal "01/01/0001 00:00:00" to type DATETIME at [27:37] [400]
    Errors [
        Message[Could not cast literal "01/01/0001 00:00:00" to type DATETIME at [27:37]] 
        Location[q - parameter] Reason[invalidQuery] Domain[global]
    ]
```

What I'm not understanding is that, the variables I use to store the date values are already of DateTime, like for example, `newRequest.deal_closed_date`. Maybe the format is wrong?

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: because DateTime is a non-nullable value type. 01/01/0001 00:00:00 ,its default value., change it to DateTime?

Comment: Also could be that `date` should send different date format

Comment: You need to [use parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) to avoid leaving your code vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occured because you are inserting data in string to a column with [DATETIME data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime_type) in BigQuery.

[image]

[image]

Convert your data first from String to DateTime data type before inserting into BigQuery. You can do this by using the [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_)  method:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString);
```

Comment: Something a forgot to say is that my variables that receive dates are already of type DateTime.

Comment: @MatheusSouzaSilva if that's the case then Richard's comment is correct, you would need to use [parameterized queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries) to help prevent SQL injection.